# Avoid division by zero in LINQ orderby

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to order by the average score without dividing by zero:

```
var articles = (from f in DB.faqs
               orderby f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum descending
               select new Article(f.ID, f.question, f.scoreSum, f.scoreCount))
               .Take(wantedItems);
```

Is there any way to achieve this in LINQ?

Comment: maybe add `where f.scoreSum > 0` :)

Comment: did you try to use where ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx

Comment: how about "orderby (f.scoreSum == 0 ? 0 : f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum) descending"?

Comment: did you mean `f.scoreSum / f.scoreCount` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you want zero-score articles to be in the end:

```
orderby f.scoreSum == 0 ? 0 : f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum descending
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
orderby (f.scoreSum != 0) ? f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum : 0.0 descending
```

Comment: The scores can't be floats (they would have no trouble dividing by zero), so that shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to linq:

```
f.scoreSum == 0 ? (f.scoreCount < 0 ? int.MinValue : int.MaxValue) : f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum
```

If not zero, it will do the regular division. If zero, it will take the closest integer to the right infinity (the one you would have gotten if you were using floats) so int.MinValue for where the result would have been negative infinity and int.MaxValue where the result would have been positive infinity.

Caveat: 0/0 also results in "as close to positive infinity as possible", if that's not ok you can add yet an other nested ternary .. or just filter the 0/0 cases out because 0/0 isn't really sortable anywhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try just checking for 0 before doing the divide.

```
var articles = (from f in DB.faqs
           orderby f.scoreSum == 0 ? 0 : f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum descending
           select new Article(f.ID, f.question, f.scoreSum, f.scoreCount))
           .Take(wantedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var articles = (from f in DB.faqs
           orderby f.scoreSum!=0? (f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum) : 0 descending
           select new Article(f.ID, f.question, f.scoreSum, f.scoreCount))
           .Take(wantedItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f.scoreSum != 0 ? f.scoreSum : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need the records where the scoreSum is 0 (invalid records?), rather than doing all of the calculations in the Orderby clause, try adding a filter on the where clause instead as that should reduce the tablescans and increase performance.

```
var articles = (from f in DB.faqs 
               where f.scoreSum != 0
               orderby f.scoreCount / f.scoreSum descending 
               select new Article(f.ID, f.question, f.scoreSum, f.scoreCount)) 
               .Take(wantedItems);
```